# Zend Framework with multiple schema/databases?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have a few tables that I've defined like the below examples:

```
class TableA extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_schema          = 'schema1';
    protected $_name            = 'tablea';
}

class TableB extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_schema          = 'schema2';
    protected $_name            = 'tableb';
}
```

This seems to work perfectly using one default Db adapter (since the 2 schemas are on the same server).

Code like this works:

```
$tableA = new TableA();
$select = $tableA->select();
// $select->__toString() outputs: SELECT * FROM `schema1`.`tablea`
```

However, when I try to use the same models with any of the Zend Framework table relationship functions (ie: findDependantRowset() or findManyToManyRowset()) the query tries to execute using the schema from the default adapter and does not use the appropriate schema that is defined in the model class.

Is this a bug? How can I force ZF to use the schema I have defined in the table class and not the one defined as the default in the default Db adapter?

Comment: Should be closed now as no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to this bug:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1838

It has been fixed in the upstream and should be available in the next release.

Comment: Thanks. If it is fixed in 1.7.3 I will close this as no longer relevent.

Answer (score -1):

I  think you can use a database view table to merge data from 2 schemas, and then use Zend Framework to fetch data from that table.

Comment: You think that is easier than ZF respecting my $_schema input?